# useage of => in join in perl

Tags: perl, join

The Perl Programming contain a piece of code like this:

```
for $family ( sort { @{$HoA{$b}} <=> @{$HoA{$a}} } keys %HoA ) {
    say "$family: ", join(", " => sort @{ $HoA{$family} });
}
```

What I'd like to know is what does the "=>" mean in the join function?

Comment: I'm resorting to the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_comma) article for this.  And this is an odd case for the fat comma in a join call.

Answer (score 6):

`=>` is generally referred to as the "fat comma".  It acts like a comma in most ways but will force any bare-word to it's left to be interpreted as a string.

In the case of this particular code snippet, is seems to be simply an uncommon stylistic choice.

Comment: That choice might have been made to help distinguish the argument separator from the actual comma in the preceding quotes.

Comment: so what's the common style choice?like this: `code`say "$family: ", join(", " ,sort @{ $HoA{$family} });`code`

Comment: Probably, but qqx's rationale has merit.

Comment: It also separates the first special arg from the rest of the list

Comment: I can see the rationale for something like: `$x = join(", " => @a, @b, @c)`.